# Spring Boot customize server.tomcat.threads.min-spare for management server only

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, tomcat, spring-boot-actuator

I have an application with management.server enabled:

`management.server.port=8081`

When I start application, I have:

- 10 threads for 8080 HTTP nio connector
- 10 threads for 8081 HTTP nio connector

But I would like to reduce min-spare only for management (8081) and not for the web application (8080)

Looking at Spring code, it seems it's not possible, can someone confirm ?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** The approach below is **not sufficient** as the `ManagementWebServerFactoryCustomizer` is also a `ConfigurableWebServerFactory` and will thus be applied to the main server.
Adding logic to check againgst the management port is not helping as the management context has its very own wiring and won't pick up the bean.

Looks like it's not possible to hook into the management server configuration easily (would be easier if `ServletManagementContextFactory` were `public`).

---

You can look into `ServletManagementChildContextConfiguration` to see how the management server is wired.

You could hook into the management server configuration by providing a `ManagementWebServerFactoryCustomizer` like this (not sure if there's an easier way):

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatManagementCustomizerConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    ManagementWebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> servletManagementWebServerFactoryCustomizer(
            @Value("${management.server.threads.min-spare:5}") int managementMinSpareThreads,
            ListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        return new TomcatManagementCustomizer(beanFactory, managementMinSpareThreads);
    }
    
    static class TomcatManagementCustomizer extends ManagementWebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> {
        private final int managementMinSpareThreads;

        protected TomcatManagementCustomizer(ListableBeanFactory beanFactory, int managementMinSpareThreads) {
            super(beanFactory, TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.class);
            this.managementMinSpareThreads = managementMinSpareThreads;
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        protected void customize(ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory factory, ManagementServerProperties managementServerProperties, ServerProperties serverProperties) {
            super.customize(factory, managementServerProperties, serverProperties);
            ((TomcatServletWebServerFactory) factory).addConnectorCustomizers((connector) -> {
                ProtocolHandler handler = connector.getProtocolHandler();
                if (handler instanceof AbstractProtocol) {
                    AbstractProtocol protocol = (AbstractProtocol) handler;
                    protocol.setMinSpareThreads(managementMinSpareThreads);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it does not work, I get ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Web server failed to start. Port 8081 was already in use.
Action:
Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8081 or configure this application to listen on another port.

Comment: @pmpm The code should not impact the ports in any way. It will just customize the management server. Are you sure there is no other process running?

Comment: Hello, yes I am sure, I started without the code and it worked, I then checked nothing was using those ports using netstat -an , enabled this code again, and it failed with this error. I made those checks multiple times. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use @ManagementConfigurationContext and add the configuration class to to your META-INF/spring.properties file.

It is also important to place the configuration class in a package which is not the main package or sub-package of your main application context. This is so that this configuration only applies to the management context.

Below is the sampel configuration following  @Holgzn's response.

```
@ManagementContextConfiguration
public class TomcatManagementCustomizerConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    ManagementWebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> servletManagementWebServerFactoryCustomizer(
            @Value("${management.server.threads.min-spare:5}") int managementMinSpareThreads,
            ListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        return new TomcatManagementCustomizer(beanFactory, managementMinSpareThreads);
    }
    
    static class TomcatManagementCustomizer extends ManagementWebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> {
        private final int managementMinSpareThreads;

        protected TomcatManagementCustomizer(ListableBeanFactory beanFactory, int managementMinSpareThreads) {
            super(beanFactory, TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.class);
            this.managementMinSpareThreads = managementMinSpareThreads;
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        protected void customize(ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory factory, ManagementServerProperties managementServerProperties, ServerProperties serverProperties) {
            super.customize(factory, managementServerProperties, serverProperties);
            ((TomcatServletWebServerFactory) factory).addConnectorCustomizers((connector) -> {
                ProtocolHandler handler = connector.getProtocolHandler();
                if (handler instanceof AbstractProtocol) {
                    AbstractProtocol protocol = (AbstractProtocol) handler;
                    protocol.setMinSpareThreads(managementMinSpareThreads);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The spring.properties file

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextConfiguration=<package>.TomcatManagementCustomizerConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just put the following in either properties file or YAML file?
Or is there something I misunderstood?

`server.tomcat.threads.min-spare=2` 
(This is for properties file)

Just to verify  (You don't need this as you have been checking the updated value in the log)

Put the following in either properties file or YAML file

`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,metrics,env` 
(This is for properties file)

And visit `/actuator/env/server.tomcat.threads.min-spare`
You need actuator dependency for the link above to work.

Comment: You didn’t get the question. I want to have a low number of threads for actuator , without impacting number of threads of my web application.I hope it’s clear now